# Database designed correctly

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am creating a  django project that has to do with dentists.
Each customer has its own set of teeth so I have a model Customer and a model Tooth with a foreignkey to customer

There is an exam called periodontogram which stores some information about each tooth like Ginginal Margin probing depth if it has implant (the tooth ) etc. I want to implement this on my project. Considering that a customer might have more than one periodontograms I decided to implement it as a model. And each periodontogram model has many periodontogram operations where each one of them consists info about each tooth. So it looks like this

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    .....
Class Tooth(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)


class Periodontogram(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    date = models.DateField()

class PeriOperation(models.Model):
    tooth = models.ForeignKey(Tooth)
    peri = models.ForeignKey(Periodontogram)
    #rest of work done per tooth
    implant = models.BooleanField()
    ginginal_margin1 = models.IntegerField()
    #...more
```

Frontend sends json data on the backend to save it. So in order to save it properly I must

1. Create new periodontogram and save it to db
2. Create operation per tooth (got from frontend)
3. assign peri field from periOperation to the periodontogram created in step 1

But what happens if some of the operations fail when creating operation per tooth. The peri will be saved but not with any operations. What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: It is probably "gingival margin", isn't it? I have life sciences background, so I noticed this medical term is wrong.

Comment: Yes it's gingival margin...That is true. Would It make a difference on my problem solution(No sarcasm..just kidding :) )?

Answer (score 5):

You should use a database transaction so all data is saved to the DB or nothing is saved. You can read more about transactions here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

You may also have to check how MySql is handling transactions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Yeah, transactions are the way to go.